# x-axis time series does not match length of time series

Tags: r, time-series

I am not sure what was wrong with my r. But when I try to plot the simulated time series data with length 300, x axis only gives maximum 30. It seems that R automatically scaled my data, which I don't want.

```
# simulation
library(astsa)
set.seed(99)
sma1 <- sarima.sim(ma=0.7, sma=-0.5, S=12, n=300)
# acf and pacf of simulated data
par(mfrow = c(1, 2)) 
acf(sma1,lag.max = 30)
pacf(sma1,lag.max = 30)
plot.ts(sma1)
```

[image]

Comment: You have asked for 300 samples at a frequency of 12, which is like asking for 300 monthly samples then plotting the x axis in years. 300 months = 25 years, which is why your plot goes up to 25. Try setting S = 1 if you want the x axis to go up to 300

Comment: Then it produced this error```Error in sarima.sim(ma = 0.7, sma = -0.5, S = 1, n = 300) : 
MA order should be less than seasonal order 'S'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using the `forecast` package.
Here's how you can do something like this:

```
set.seed(99)
sma1 <- arima.sim(n=300, list(ar = c(0.8897), ma = c(0.7, -0.5)))
autoplot(sma1)+
  ggtitle("Sample time series") 

ggAcf(sma1, lag=48)+
  ggtitle("Sample time series ACF")
```

[image]
[image]

For more information, see the amazing book [Forecasting: Principles and Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp2/)